# filter and includes showing error message

Tags: javascript, filter, include

can someone please explain to me why this is not working?

const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const filtered = numbers.filter((num) => num.includes(1));

console.log(filtered);

I am getting this message saying num.includes is not a function.

Comment: What are you trying to do

Answer (score 1):

`.includes` exists for two prototypes, [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), your array elements are of type `number` which has no such method

Answer (score 0):

`.includes()` only works on strings or arrays. You are calling on a number. You want `const filtered = numbers.filter((num) => num === 1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
numbers=numbers.map(String);//changes elements to string
const filtered = numbers.filter((num) => num.includes(1));

console.log(filtered);
```

should fix the problem